# Auto hiding behind the screen image slider for WordPress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, slider

My client is asking for  a slider plugin for wordpress those will be placed at  the header of the page. It will have multiple images fading one after another with next and previous button. But the problem is he does not want exactly responsive slider . He wants some like this link http://go-vacation.com/ . Please look at the slider of the top. Try to resize the browser width and height. The main theme is when someone resize the browser window the image is hiding behind the screen. and no scroll bar is coming.  Scroll bar will come only when the screen is resized to less than 960 pixel. Image size of the sliders  will be 1600*600 px.So suppose the screen is now at 1000px then you will  be able to see only 1000px portion of the image the rest will be hidden from both side of the screen. Please observe the behavior of http://go-vacation.com/

I am not actually the logic behind this so that I can start with CSS and js. What will be main theme to start for this. Do you have anything in your collection? If it is normal jquery slider then also no problem . I will convert it to wordpress plugin. Or any help with simple example of the main logic is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

The best WP slider I know (which is also responsive) is [FlexSlider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/). But you can use any slider you want. Just set your slider container min-width and width: 100% (if it's not set by slider itself).

Comment: Hi Alex I am using the cyclon slider. I also believe if we figure out the logic then any slider will work. Did you see the behavior of go-vaction.com ? I am going to try with your suggestions. But just to remind you this is not a responsive slider actually. The image size should not resized here when the browser window get resized. Rather the image will be hidden from both side when the window is resized.

Comment: It'll not resize image if you make it as a background. I don't know how cyclone slider render images, so you should figure that out.